# Where can I find a Status Quo?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

One of the assassination missions requires that I be driving one of the limos in the game, the Status Quo.  I've seen them from time to time (normally when I'm wanting a high-speed getaway vehicle they're everywhere!) but I've been driving around the city looking for one to no avail.

Is there some place where one is parked that I can grab it?  Failing that, do they spawn frequently in some area?

I'm done with the missions and side activities for the most part, so if there's one that's missable, I probably have missed it by now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few sitting outside of Safeword (the BDSM club you go to in one of the story missions), not sure if you need to do the mission before they spawn there, though.

Comment: This is a good place to find them late in the game: limos do spawn once you've made it your crib, so all you have to do is go there and pick one up (in the front, though, not in the back where the entrance to the garage is).

Comment: Confirmed this in my game, with Safeword maxed out as a crib, there are two sitting in the driveway.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find any just use this cheat: `givestatusquo`. It is really cool and you can customize it too if you get it.

It will appear in any of your safehouses when you click it on the cheats menu. It will be on the vehicle section of your cheat menu.

Comment: If you use that cheat, it will prohibit any and all achievements.

Answer (score 1):

Every now and then they pop up on the bridge, around Rim Jobs, near a safe house, by Friendly Fire, and/or near your crib.